# Flash scenes - more efficient than using mcs or frames?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, scene

I am making a game and was wondering whether scenes have any efficiency/performance purpose or if they're just there to make Flash more organized?

Comment: Also, if you don't absolutely *need* to use `MovieClip`s, don't. If a `Sprite` or a `Shape` can do the job, you will end up with infinitely faster code than if you were to only use `MovieClip`s everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a game I guess there is some coding involved. In flash community it is common convention not to use scenes except for swf MOVIES and yet I don't remember anyone using scenes for a long time.

Scenes might not add performance overhead but they make your app more complicated. They can't be created with code, you have to be sure that your MovieClip is not only at the right frame but is in the right scene. And there are more. I stopped using scenes long time ago after desperate struggling with unexplainable behavior. And if you are new to flash I advise you just not to use scenes whatever someone might say.

Answer (score 0):

They're are there only to make Flash movies more organized. They have no performance benefit at all.